# How to use SearchView in Toolbar Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview, android-toolbar

The code on which I am working, is using a `Toolbar` and inflating a `menu`.

Here is the code

```
private Toolbar mToolbar;
mToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.chat_screen_menu);
setupMenu ();
private void setupMenu ()
   {
   mMenu = mToolbar.getMenu();
   if (mMenu != null)
      {
       if (mChatPager != null && mChatPager.getCurrentItem() > 0)
          {
          mMenu.setGroupVisible(R.id.menu_group_chats, true);
          mMenu.setGroupVisible(R.id.menu_group_contacts, false);
          }
       else
          {
           mMenu.setGroupVisible(R.id.menu_group_chats, false);
           mMenu.setGroupVisible(R.id.menu_group_contacts, true);
           mMenu.setGroupVisible(R.id.menu_group_otr_verified,false);
           mMenu.setGroupVisible(R.id.menu_group_otr_unverified,false);
           mMenu.setGroupVisible(R.id.menu_group_otr_off,false);
          }
    }
    mToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener ()
    {
    ..........
    }
}
```

But now, they require a `Search` button in the `tool_bar`.
I managed to put it, I followed a guide [here](https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html#create-sa)
When I try to write something to search, the toast I had put to test the `listener` never shown. 
which indicates `listener` is not working

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.chat_screen_menu, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_menu_search));
    final Toast toast = new Toast(mApp);

    if (mSearchView != null )
    {
        mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

        SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
        {
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
            {
                mSearchString = newText;
                //doFilterAsync(mSearchString);
                toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            }

            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
            {
                mSearchString = query;
                //doFilterAsync(mSearchString);
                toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                return true;
            }
        };

        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);
    }

    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 219, accepted):

You have to use `Appcompat` library for that. Which is used like below:

**dashboard.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="Search"/>
</menu>
```

**Activity file (in Java):**

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.dashboard, menu);

     MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

    SearchView searchView = null;
    if (searchItem != null) {
        searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    }
    if (searchView != null) {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(MainActivity.this.getComponentName()));
    }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**Activity file (in Kotlin):**

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu)

    val searchItem: MenuItem? = menu?.findItem(R.id.action_search)
    val searchManager = getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE) as SearchManager
    val searchView: SearchView? = searchItem?.actionView as SearchView

    searchView?.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(componentName))
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
}
```

**manifest file:**

```
<meta-data 
      android:name="android.app.default_searchable" 
      android:value="com.apkgetter.SearchResultsActivity" /> 

        <activity
            android:name="com.apkgetter.SearchResultsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
```

**searchable xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

And at last, your `SearchResultsActivity` class code. for showing result of your search.

Comment: Note that now you should `import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`

Comment: Thanks, any idea as how to handle the "Go" click? it would help

Comment: I will just link the official documentation where you can also find how to react to the query
https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html

Comment: Note the   app:actionViewClass   instead of   android:actionViewClass

Comment: How can i return search result from SearchResultsActivity to MaiActivity?

Comment: <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> - is redundant? Working without it.

Comment: You should update your answer and add `app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"`

Comment: If you've migrated to androidX use: `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView`

Answer (score 184):

If you would like to setup the search facility inside your `Fragment`, just add these few lines:

**Step 1** - Add the search field to you `toolbar`:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:title="Search"/>
```

**Step 2** - Add the logic to your `onCreateOptionsMenu()`

```
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView; // not the default !

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.main, menu);

    MenuItem myActionMenuItem = menu.findItem( R.id.action_search);
    searchView = (SearchView) myActionMenuItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            // Toast like print
            UserFeedback.show( "SearchOnQueryTextSubmit: " + query);
            if( ! searchView.isIconified()) {
                searchView.setIconified(true);
            }
            myActionMenuItem.collapseActionView();
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            // UserFeedback.show( "SearchOnQueryTextChanged: " + s);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This answer is far more helpful if you don't want to create/move to a new activity when a user has submitted the search query. This will allow you to stay on the same activity/fragment and just update a view based on the users input. Great stuff.

Comment: UserFeedback ... is my Toast-alike method.

Comment: Keyboard input not taken in search view

Comment: What's `R.menu.main`?

Comment: public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
} you can directly call this method here you can infilate own menu, and handle this directoly from from fragment without using activity. nice thanks

Answer (score 43):

If you want to add it directly in the toolbar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            android:queryHint="Search"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: If you are using the support SearchView, don't forget to declare it as `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` in the XML, too.

Comment: don't forget to add in gradle `implementation 'com.android.support:design:$latest_version'`

Comment: What is **iconified**?

Comment: ¨If you want the search field to always be visible, then call setIconifiedByDefault(false)¨ from the docs

Answer (score 22):

## Integrating SearchView with RecyclerView

#### 1) Add SearchView Item in Menu

`SearchView` can be added as `actionView` in menu using

> app:useActionClass = "android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
>   .

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="rohksin.com.searchviewdemo.MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/searchBar"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    />
</menu>
```

#### 2) Implement SearchView.OnQueryTextListener in your Activity

`SearchView.OnQueryTextListener` has two abstract methods. So your activity skeleton would now look like this after implementing SearchView text listener.

```
YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{

   public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)

   public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) 

}
```

#### 3) Set up SerchView Hint text, listener etc

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.searchBar);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setQueryHint("Search People");
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    searchView.setIconified(false);

    return true;
}
```

#### 4) Implement SearchView.OnQueryTextListener

This is how you can implement abstract methods of the listener.

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

    // This method can be used when a query is submitted eg. creating search history using SQLite DB

    Toast.makeText(this, "Query Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

    adapter.filter(newText);
    return true;
}
```

#### 5) Write a filter method in your RecyclerView Adapter.

You can come up with your own logic based on your requirement. Here is the sample code snippet to show the list of Name which contains the text typed in the `SearchView`.

```
public void filter(String queryText)
{
    list.clear();

    if(queryText.isEmpty())
    {
        list.addAll(copyList);
    }
    else
    {

        for(String name: copyList)
        {
            if(name.toLowerCase().contains(queryText.toLowerCase()))
            {
                list.add(name);
            }
        }

    }

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Full working code sample can be found > [HERE](https://github.com/rohitksingh/My_Android_Garage/tree/master/SearchViewDemo)
You can also check out the code on SearchView with an SQLite database in this [Music App](https://github.com/rohitksingh/OLA_Play_Music_App)

Comment: Why is menu necessary?

Answer (score 4):

**Implementing the SearchView without the use of the `menu.xml` file and open through button**

In your `Activity` we need to use the method of the `onCreateOptionsMenu`method in which we will programmatically inflate the `SearchView`

```
private MenuItem searchMenu;
private String mSearchString="";

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) StoreActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);


        SearchView mSearchView = new SearchView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
        mSearchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.prompt_search)); /// YOUR HINT MESSAGE
        mSearchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        searchMenu = menu.add("searchMenu").setVisible(false).setActionView(mSearchView);
        searchMenu.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);


        assert searchManager != null;
        mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

        SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                mSearchString = newText;

                return true;
            }

            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                mSearchString = query;

                searchMenu.collapseActionView();


                return true;
            }
        };

        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);


        return true;
    }
```

And in your Activity class, you can open the `SearchView` on any button click on toolbar like below

```
YOUR_BUTTON.setOnClickListener(view -> {

            searchMenu.expandActionView();

        });
```

Answer (score -2):

I search and implement so much code but that not worked for me .
Then I implement custom toolbar into my XML file and then inside toolbar tag I use searchview tag.
Hope it work for you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).