# Implementing SearchView in Toolbar with Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, searchview

**CURRENT SCENARIO**

My app home page consists of navigation drawer, therefore I am having views loaded as fragments. I also have search icon in toolbar. I implemented it in **menu.xml**. Next step I implemented `SearchView` for search icon by following answer on this question
[Implementing search in Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378981/how-to-use-searchview-in-toolbar-android).

This is working fine as search view shows and can also be dismissed.

**PROBLEM**

I can implement search query for the search view but I cannot understand how to proceed. 
Problem is that `onCreateOptionsMenu` is in `Activity` and all code for search view is in the `Activity`. 
What I don't understand is data that has to be searched is in `Fragment` that is loaded in `Activity` class. I will hit another webservice to get the search result but how would I inflate searched data in `Fragment` again. I can't understand how to proceed in this situation.

Comment: `My app home page consists of navigation drawer, therefore I am having views loaded as fragments.` no, `DrawerLayout` does not require `Fragment`s to be used

Comment: I think best practice is to do it this way

Comment: who said that? where did you read it?

Comment: We were taught this in training

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put this in your fragment

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

And you can get the **SearchView** like follows

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem mSearchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.mi_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) mSearchMenuItem.getActionView();
}
```

Comment: Ho will I get text written in searchview?? Should I have to implement textChangeListener

Comment: Implement a query text listener on the searchview as follows: searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener())

Comment: I am getting superNotCalled error when navigate to the fragment

Comment: return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu); at the end of the onPrepareOptionsMenu

Comment: It's a void method how it can return?

Comment: Now it says incompatible type on return statement. Required boolean found void

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101382/discussion-between-vivek-mishra-and-malek-hijazi).

Comment: Hi Malek I cant access the searchitem click event in fragment please help me

Comment: This work perfect on Navigation Drawer with Fragments. Thanks a lot!.