# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I am trying to integrate simple map app with a place search functionality and I am facing the problem is that searching bar is not coming out in the map. I'm not sure what is the reason, as i'm beginner in android. however `onCreateOptionsMenu` code is as follow, please any solution would be very thankful.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        // get a reference to the EditText widget for the search option
        View searchRef = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        mSearchEditText = (EditText) searchRef.findViewById(R.id.searchText);

        // set key listener to start search if Enter key is pressed
        mSearchEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    onSearchButtonClicked(mSearchEditText);
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
```

**Error:**

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.example.adrian.placesearch.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:106)

Comment: Which line in this snippet is Line106 ? Does the menu_main layout contain action_search entry ?

Comment: I also asked the same question regarding searchview few days ago. Here is the linik to that question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34942492/implementing-searchview-in-toolbar-with-fragments

Comment: please post your `R.menu.menu_main` xml code

Comment: line 106: mSearchEditText=(EditText) searchRef.findViewById(R.id.searchText);

Comment: Try using the searchview from appcompat class as actionViewClass in the menu.xml.Instead use app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView".Use this instead and let me know if its solving the purpose

Comment: For the menu_main, I just follow coding in the website
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     tools:context=".MainActivity">
     <item
         android:id="@+id/action_search"
         app:actionLayout="@layout/search_layout"
         android:title="@string/action_search"
         android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
         app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />
 </menu>

Comment: Paste the code of this file app:actionLayout="@layout/search_layout" here

Comment: @AndroidMech 
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/search_layout"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />

try already but problem still exist