# Can't get SearchView in actionbar to work

Tags: android, list, listview, search, searchview

I have tried a lot of tutorials, stackoverflow solutions, and the google tutorial -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9OWmnYPX1uc but I can't get the searchview in my actionbar to work.

does anyone sees what I am doing wrong?

I Always get a nullpointerexception on the searchView

**My Activity with the listview:**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list_menu, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(
            new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    Toast.makeText(ContactListActivity.this, query, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    Toast.makeText(ContactListActivity.this, newText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }
            }
    );

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), TorrentListActivity.class);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(componentName));
    return true;
}
```

**Searchable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="Search"
    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"/>
```

**list_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="be.vanlooverenkoen.torrentsearch.TorrentListActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

**EDIT 1**

[image]
I wan't the suggestions on 1 Activity but on another activity I need to filter the list of my listview

**EDIT 2 **

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import be.vanlooverenkoen.torrentsearch.CommonUtilities.CommonUtilities;
import be.vanlooverenkoen.torrentsearch.model.Torrent;
/**
 * Created by Koen on 19/03/2016.
 */
public class TorrentListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LinkedList<Torrent> torrents;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    public TorrentListAdapter(Context context, LinkedList<Torrent> torrents) {
        this.torrents = torrents;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return torrents.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return torrents.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.titleView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
            holder.seedView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_seedsValue);
            holder.peerView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_peersValue);
            holder.sizeView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_sizeValue);
            holder.dateView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_datevalue);
            holder.torrentTypeTitleView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.torrenttypetitle);
            holder.torrentTypeView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.torrentTypeView);
            holder.verifiedImg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.verified);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        Torrent torrent = torrents.get(position);
        holder.titleView.setText(torrent.getTitle());
        Log.d("Seeds", String.valueOf(holder.titleView.getText()));
        holder.seedView.setText(String.valueOf(torrent.getSeeds()));
        holder.peerView.setText(String.valueOf(torrent.getPeers()));
        holder.sizeView.setText(torrent.getSize());
        holder.dateView.setText(torrent.getDateOfRelease());
        if(CommonUtilities.checkForShowTorrentType(layoutInflater.getContext())){
            holder.torrentTypeView.setText(torrent.getTorrentType());
            holder.torrentTypeTitleView.setText("Torrent Type:");
        }else{
            holder.torrentTypeView.setText("");
            holder.torrentTypeTitleView.setText("");
        }
        if (torrent.isLegitUploader()) {
            holder.verifiedImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.verified);
        }else{
            holder.verifiedImg.setImageDrawable(null);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView titleView;
        TextView seedView;
        TextView peerView;
        TextView sizeView;
        TextView dateView;
        TextView torrentTypeTitleView;
        TextView torrentTypeView;
        ImageView verifiedImg;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 3**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: be.vanlooverenkoen.torrentsearch, PID: 10509
                                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$OnQueryTextListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                      at be.vanlooverenkoen.torrentsearch.TorrentListActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(TorrentListActivity.java:105)
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2852)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:298)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:85)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:241)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1273)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1553)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.access$100(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:89)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$1.run(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:129)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**SOLUTION**

OMG
android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
must be
app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"

and then poof it works

Comment: I advice to use toolbar for this instead of action bar. I can walk you through that.

Comment: EDIT 1 = what I want if it looks the same it is oke for me ;)

Comment: Alright, do you know how to implement toolbar for your activity?

Comment: If not follow this, its simple really http://javatechig.com/android/android-lollipop-toolbar-example

Comment: Then we can add edittext as our searchview and implement filterable.

Comment: Nowp, i'm now programming for 6 months. Java i have experience for 1.5 years now. so no I don't know how to implement a toolbar.

Comment: Alright, you can follow the link above to see if it's doable. I'd also advice to use more of toolbar. Gives you more "freedom" to customize the look and functionality. I am currently using the search feature i have briefed about on my listview and Gridview.

Comment: Oke I will try to figure this out, when I'm done, I will let you know

Comment: Sure sure go ahead :)

Comment: Oke I have implemented the toolbar, but only 1 question needed to change my them but now all my colors are different, everything is dark instead of light

Comment: Let's deal with the search first.

Comment: Oke ;) that's fine for me

Comment: I am assuming you have an adapter too? Paste code for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your list_menu.xml,

```
android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
```

should be changed to:

```
app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't post the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, I guess you haven't changed it. You should add:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
           android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
```

to `<activity android:name=".TorrentListActivity" ... >` tag to let your app know it can search in it.

Tutorial I used: http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html

Comment: I forgot to post that indeed but I did exactly what you wrote

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `Toolbar` layout add an `EditText`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#2196F3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_transparent"
            android:hint="Search..."
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColorHint="#fff" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

edit_text_transparent.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <stroke
        android:width="0dp"
        android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

In your activity find the `EditText` widget by referencing it and add a `TextWatcher` to filter results:

```
 inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text

                if (cs.length() > 0) {
                   adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
                } else {

                  //no search results were returned

                    TextView search = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.no_results);
                    search.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

 adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```

**EDIT**

Have you added this namespace inside your search item in menu.xml:

```
 app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
```

And also in manifest:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
```

Comment: this always gives me a searchview, I wan't a button and if I press that button the field expand over the whole toolbaar/actionbar,

Comment: and I have a Custom adapter, can't getFilter(); om my adapter

Comment: Nowp, the icon i floading over the EditText,

Comment: I get it. There's a way to do that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378981/how-to-use-searchview-in-toolbar-android

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108295/discussion-between-koen-van-looveren-and-steve-kamau).