# SearchView in Toolbar implemented by Activity

Tags: android, searchview

In the app I'm trying to do, I want to implement search, that will call a rest api.

As I asked long Time ago on how to do a SearchView it works ok --> [How to use SearchView in Toolbar Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378981/how-to-use-searchview-in-toolbar-android)

But now I want to try something "different" (To learn a little bit more). But I'm doing something wrong.

What I'm trying to do is make the Activity implmement `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener` , so whay I have is:

```
    public class PMov extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {    
    ....
    @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "TextSubmit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Logger.d("onQueryTextSubmit: " + query);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "TextChange", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Logger.d("onQueryTextChange: " + newText);
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"/>
</menu>
```

But for some reason (for sure I'm missing something) the methods are not triggered when I click and "write" something in the SearchBox.

What I'm missing?  All the example I found are similar to my post I did long time ago.

Comment: I'm guessing you have to tell SearchView what is listening I.e. `setOnQueryTextListener(this)`

Comment: not sure , but have you tried calling `setOnQueryTextListener` on searchView and using anonymous inner class for `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()` instead of implementing in activity , that works for me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the solution... facepalm for me!

as @Markkeen pointend, I was missing tell to SearchView who is listening, it becomes fixed doing this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView actionSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        actionSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    }
```

And with this, the methods `onQueryTextSubmit` and `onQueryTextChange` are trigged.

Thanks!