# SearchView in Android Bar

Tags: android, searchview

I am so confused how to make the searchview in android bar. It's the 2 days now stuck in this scenario. If someone can help me with my codes below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    private static final int EDITOR_REQUEST_CODE = 1001;
    private CursorAdapter cursorAdapter;

    MediaPlayer mySound;
    private AdView mAdView;

    //If media player stop
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mySound.release();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mySound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.door);

        //Adsence Ads to load
        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-8674376475299935~1764444800");
        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        cursorAdapter = new NotesCursorAdapter(this, null, 0);

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditorActivity.class);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(NotesProvider.CONTENT_URI + "/" + id);
                intent.putExtra(NotesProvider.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, uri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, EDITOR_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

    }

    //Search bar call

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_view_menu_item, menu);
        MenuItem searchViewItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchViewAndroidActionBar = (SearchView) searchViewItem.getActionView();
        searchViewAndroidActionBar.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                //searchViewAndroidActionBar.clearFocus();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                cursorAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

                return false;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

And here my class NotesCursorAdapter

```
public class NotesCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    public NotesCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.note_list_item, parent, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        String noteText = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBOpenHelper.NOTE_TEXT));

        int pos = noteText.indexOf(10);
        if (pos != - 1){
            noteText = noteText.substring(0, pos) + "...";
        }

        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvNote);
        tv.setText(noteText);

    }
}
```

The above is the code which I intended to do searchview functionality but I cant make it to work.

Comment: Is this your implemented code or you trying to implement from a tutorial?

Comment: I derived the codes above based on the tutorial and implement my learning as part of my exercise to determine how far I can go with android. I ask for solution to make my learning propel.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the SearchView in toolbar in youractivity.xml file like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            android:queryHint="Search"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Then you need to cast searchView in your code and do functionality based on your requirements. See the similar question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378981/how-to-use-searchview-in-toolbar-android)