# Accordion is not working in my android app

Tags: android, accordion

i am trying to use accordion future in my android app . but that future is not working.Please

assist me

Below are my source code

activity_main

Below are my source code
Below are my source code

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.muslim.bootstrap.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/mybrowser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </WebView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

my java file

Below are my source code

Below are my source code

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView MyBrowser;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView MyBrowser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mybrowser);
        MyBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }
}
```

html file

Below are my source code

Below are my source code

Below are my source code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Accordion</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .bs-example{
     margin: 20px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bs-example">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">1. What is HTML?</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>HTML stands for HyperText Markup Language. HTML is the standard markup language for describing the structure of web pages. <a href="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">2. What is Bootstrap?</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>Bootstrap is a sleek, intuitive, and powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development. It is a collection of CSS and HTML conventions. <a href="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">3. What is CSS?</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheet. CSS allows you to specify various style properties for a given HTML element such as colors, backgrounds, fonts etc. <a href="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p><strong>Note:</strong> Click on the linked heading text to expand or collapse accordion panels.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Below are my source code
Below are my source code

Below are my source code

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.muslim.bootstrap">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

i am trying to use accordion future in my android app . but that future is not working

please help

Comment: Is this url working fine on browser?

Comment: yes its is working

Comment: is this the url "file:///android_asset/index.html"?

Comment: yes its in asset folder

Comment: i able view the see the screen but the accordion feature is not working

Comment: have a look at this tutorial it might help.
https://inducesmile.com/android-tutorials-for-nigerian-developer/loading-html-file-from-assets-folder-in-android-webview/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modification in your Mainactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView MyBrowser;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView MyBrowser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mybrowser);

        // For allowing Javascript
        WebSettings settings = MyBrowser.getSettings();
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

        MyBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }
}
```

and also make sure in XML. your web view's height and width should be match_parent

Comment: Welcome ... Good Day.

Comment: can you tell me how add search option for this as well

Comment: Where do you want to add Search option?

Comment: at the top of the page

Comment: Use toolbar for Search option   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378981/how-to-use-searchview-in-toolbar-android

Answer (score 0):

```
WebView MyBrowser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mybrowser);      
WebSettings webSettings = MyBrowser.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
MyBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

Try this ,you have to  enable javascript