# SearchView in a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview

*I am trying to filter my RecyclerView list according to whatever I type in my SearchView.*

**RecyclerView Layout Code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
tools:context=".Reciever.Reciever_Recycler.RecieveBlood">

<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/Donar_Search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="visible"></SearchView>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/DonarList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

**Code For my RecyclerView Where i have declare my SearchView :**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_recieve_blood );
    searchView = (SearchView)findViewById( R.id.Donar_Search );
    new ShowDonar().execute();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener( new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            RAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            return false;
        }
    } );
}
```

**Code For my RecyclerView Adapter :**

```
public class RecieverAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements Filterable{
Context context;
List<BloodData> data = Collections.emptyList();
List<BloodData> searchData;
LayoutInflater inflater;
RecieverAdapter RAdapter;
LocationManager locationManager;
MyHolder myHolder;

public RecieverAdapter(RecieveBlood recieveBlood, List<BloodData> data) {
    this.context = recieveBlood;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from( context );
    this.data = data;
    this.RAdapter = this;
    searchData = new ArrayList<>( data );
    locationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.blood_list, viewGroup, false );
    MyHolder holder = new MyHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    myHolder = (MyHolder) viewHolder;
    BloodData current = data.get( i );
    myHolder.Sr_Num.setText( " "+i );
    myHolder.Donar_Name.setText( "Name : "+current.getD_Name() );
    myHolder.Donar_Blood_Group.setText( "Blood Group : " +current.getD_blood_group());
    myHolder.Donar_Mobile.setText( "Mobile : "+current.getD_Number());
    myHolder.Donar_Gender.setText( "Gender : "+current.getD_Gender());
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return donarFilter;
}

private Filter donarFilter = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        List<BloodData> filteredList = new ArrayList<>(  );

        if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){
            filteredList.addAll( searchData );
        }else {
            String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

            for(BloodData item : searchData){
                if (item.D_blood_group.toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                    filteredList.add(item);
                }else if (item.D_Name.toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                    filteredList.add(item);
                }else if (item.D_Gender.toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                    filteredList.add(item);
                }
            }
        }

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        results.values = filteredList;

        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        searchData.clear();
        searchData.addAll( (List) results.values );
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};

private class MyHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView Sr_Num,Donar_Name,Donar_Blood_Group,Donar_Mobile,Donar_Gender;
    Button location1, location2;
    public MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super( itemView );

        Sr_Num = (TextView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.sr_number );
        Donar_Name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.Donar_Name );
        Donar_Blood_Group  =(TextView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.Donar_blood_Group);
        Donar_Mobile = (TextView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.Donar_Number );
        Donar_Gender = (TextView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.Donar_Gender );
        location1 = (Button) itemView.findViewById( R.id.location1 );
        location2 = (Button) itemView.findViewById( R.id.location2 );
    }
}
```

**This my data code :**

```
public class BloodData {
    public String D_Name;
    public String D_blood_group;
    public String D_Gender;
    public String D_Number;




    public BloodData(String D_Name, String D_blood_group, String D_Gender){
        this.D_Name = D_Name;
        this.D_blood_group = D_blood_group;
        this.D_Gender = D_Gender;

    }

    public String getD_Name() {
        return D_Name;
    }

    public String getD_blood_group() {
        return D_blood_group;
    }

    public String getD_Gender() {
        return D_Gender;
    }

    public String getD_Number() {
        return D_Number;
    }
}
```

In this whenever I type something in my SearchView the list doesn't get filter. 
It stays as it.
I am not getting where i'm wrong please help out.

Comment: You need update *data* list with *search-filter* data..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378981/how-to-use-searchview-in-toolbar-android/49064027#49064027 See this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should update data list instead of updating searchData list.

```
@Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        data.clear();
        data.addAll( (List) results.values );
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Can you help me out in one more thing

Comment: When the recyclerView Activity opens **No data list should be show** and When i type something in my searchView the the filtered list should shown.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search list items by name, the easiest solution is to use `onTextChangedListener` for your searchView, then on text change - get adapter list, filter it, update with filtered list and finally set `notifyDataSetChanged()` method on your adapter.

You could also use libraries, for example that one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30429439/9941595

Comment: Can you help me out in one more thing.
When the recyclerView Activity opens **No data list should be show** and **When i type something in my searchView the the filtered list should shown**.