# RecyclerView pagination with Filter feature

Tags: android, android-studio, pagination, android-recyclerview

I need one example which has `Recyclerview` pagination with search feature.

`Recyclerview` pagination is working but I am unable to add the filtration feature with `Recyclerview` pagination. I am using `EndlessRecyclerView` which I found from Github.

Comment: What is the filtration feature? Can you share some code snippet for better understanding.

Comment: Paste the code you've tried so far.

Comment: See this might help you for the Filter part https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378981/how-to-use-searchview-in-toolbar-android/49064027#49064027