# how add search filter bar in listview kotlin

Tags: android, listview, kotlin

l  have created a list view and the code working fine . also created a search box . I want to implement search functionality on the basis of particular fields of the list. l used list adapter in Separated class is not in main activity class . l want use search bar filter in class list adapter .

main activity class

```
package com.iraqairoirt.iraqairports

import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.os.AsyncTask
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter
import android.os.Bundle

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_arrivel.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_dep.*
import org.json.JSONArray
import org.json.JSONObject
import java.net.HttpURLConnection
import java.net.URL

import android.widget.TextView
import com.iraqairoirt.iraqairports.flightsDep.ListAdapteDep
import com.iraqairoirt.iraqairports.flightsArr.ListAdapteArr


    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


        private var mSectionsPagerAdapter: SectionsPagerAdapter? = null

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)




            val url = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            Arr().execute(url)
            Dep().execute(url)


            setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
            // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
            // primary sections of the activity.
            mSectionsPagerAdapter = SectionsPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)

            // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
            container.adapter = mSectionsPagerAdapter

            container.addOnPageChangeListener(TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabs))
            tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(container))


        }
        //    full class for json api
        inner class Arr : AsyncTask<String, String, String>(){

            val progressDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
            val dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.progress_dialog,null)
            val message = dialogView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.message_id)
            val dialog = progressDialog.create()

            override fun onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute()

                dialog.setMessage("loading")
                dialog.setCancelable(false)
                dialog.show()


            }

            //        for build connection
            override fun doInBackground(vararg url: String?): String{

                var text : String
                val connection = URL(url[0]).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection

                try {
                    connection.connect()
                    text = connection.inputStream.use { it.reader().use{reader -> reader.readText()} }


                } finally{

                    connection.disconnect()

                }
                return text
            }

            override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {

                super.onPostExecute(result)
                handleJson(result)

                dialog.dismiss();

            }

            override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg text: String?) {


            }
            private fun handleJson (jsonString: String?){

                val schedule = pluginData.getJSONObject("schedule")
                val arrivals = schedule.getJSONObject("arrivals")
    //        val data = arrivals.getJSONObject("data")
                val jsonArray = JSONArray(arrivals.get("data").toString())

                val list =  ArrayList<FlightShdu>()
                var x = 0
                while (x < jsonArray.length()){

                    val jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(x)



                    list.add(FlightShdu(
                        jsonObject.getJSONObject("flight").getJSONObject("identification").getJSONObject("number").getString("default"),
                        jsonObject.getJSONObject("flight").getJSONObject("airline").getString("short"),
                        jsonObject.getJSONObject("flight").getJSONObject("status").getJSONObject("generic").getJSONObject("status").getString("text"),
                        jsonObject.getJSONObject("flight").getJSONObject("airline").getJSONObject("code").getString("icao"),
                        jsonObject.getJSONObject("flight").getJSONObject("time").getJSONObject("scheduled").getString("arrival"),
                        jsonObject.getJSONObject("flight").getJSONObject("airport").getJSONObject("origin").getJSONObject("code").getString("iata"),
                        jsonObject.getJSONObject("flight").getJSONObject("aircraft").getJSONObject("model").getString("text"),
    //                    for more information
                        jsonObject.getJSONObject("flight").getJSONObject("time").getJSONObject("real").getString("departure"),
                        jsonObject.getJSONObject("flight").getJSONObject("time").getJSONObject("estimated").getString("arrival"),
    //                    jsonObject.getJSONObject("flight").getJSONObject("time").getJSONObject("estimated").getString("arrival"),
                        jsonObject.getJSONObject("flight").getJSONObject("aircraft").getString("registration"),
                        jsonObject.getJSONObject("flight").getJSONObject("status").getJSONObject("generic").getJSONObject("status").getString("diverted"),
                        arrivals.getString("timestamp"),
                        jsonObject.getJSONObject("flight").getJSONObject("status").getString("icon")





                        ))


                    x++
                }
                list.forEach(::println)

                val adapter = ListAdapteArr(this@MainActivity, list)
                flight_arrivel_list.adapter = adapter




            }




        }




        /**
         * A [FragmentPagerAdapter] that returns a fragment corresponding to
         * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
         */
        inner class SectionsPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {

            override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {

                return when (position) {
                    0 -> {
                        fragment_Arr()
                    }
                    1 ->{

                        fragment_Dep()
                    }
                    2->{
                        fragment_Weather()
                    }
                    else-> {
                        return null
                    }
                }

            }

            override fun getCount(): Int {
                // Show 3 total pages.
                return 2
            }

        }


    }
```

List Adapter

```
   class ListAdapteArr (val context: MainActivity, val list: ArrayList<FlightShdu>): BaseAdapter() {
        @SuppressLint("ViewHolder", "NewApi")
        override fun getView(p0: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {

            val view : View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.arr_list,parent,false)


            val searchBar = view.findViewById(R.id.searchFlightId) as MaterialSearchBar

            Airport.text= list.Airport




            return view

        }




        override fun getItem(p0: Int): Any {
            return list [p0]
        }

        override fun getItemId(p0: Int): Long {
            return p0.toLong()
        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return list.size
        }



    }
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/flight_arrivel_list"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView"
            android:paddingStart="10sp"
            android:paddingEnd="10sp"
            android:paddingTop="0dp" android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="58dp" android:layout_marginStart="0dp"/>
    <com.mancj.materialsearchbar.MaterialSearchBar
            style="@style/MaterialSearchBarLight"
            app:mt_speechMode="true"
            app:mt_hint="Custom hint"
            app:mt_maxSuggestionsCount="10"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/searchBar" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

l added search bar filter to search on any item inside listview but the there still not funcation to do this

Comment: Are you wanting to search and apply the search results to the `ListView`?

Comment: yes . l want search item from inside the list view example like this https://youtu.be/ZuFC3C3NpX0 . but l want to apply this steps on my code above .

Comment: Do you have answer code please

Comment: Sorry Pablo, was too busy yesterday, posted answer now

Comment: I dont know how to code in Kotlin. But if you know Java then maybe this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378981/how-to-use-searchview-in-toolbar-android/49064027#49064027

Comment: unfortunately l dont know things in java , thank you for try help

Answer (score 1):

In your activity perform your search on your list and reassign the value(keep a `val baseList` and `var filteredList` so you can default back to the original if need be. First of all we want to move the nested adapter to the top of the activity so we can access it after its instantiated. We also want to use two lists for this so aff the `baseList` and `filteredList` as i have below the `private lateinit var adapter: ListAdapteArr? = null` at the top of the activity.

```
private lateinit var adapter: ListAdapteArr? = null

private var baseList: List<FlightShdu> = listOf()
private var filteredList: MutableList<FlightShdu> = mutableListOf()
```

In your `handleJson()` method, once the list has been populated with all the `FlightShdu` objects, assign it to the `baseList`

```
baseList = list
```

Then assign your `private lateinit var adapter`:

```
 adapter = ListAdapteArr(this@MainActivity, baseList)
                flight_arrivel_list.adapter = adapter
```

Have a method that takes the edit text search term and compares it with your list

```
   fun searchList() {
       filteredList.clear()
       baseList.forEach { 
       if (it.contains(search.text.toString())) {
          filteredList.add(it)
       }
    }
    adapter.updateList(filteredList)
```

Then within your adapter change:

`val list: ArrayList<FlightShdu>` to `var list: ArrayList<FlightShdu>`

and have a method like:

```
 fun updateList(filteredList: List<FlightShdu>) {
    list.clear()
    list.addAll(filteredList)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
 }
```

With the updated list in activity, call the method with `adapter.updateList(filteredList)`

I would also recommend using a `recyclerview` instead of a `listview`
[RecyclerView vs. ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728651/recyclerview-vs-listview)

You could also look into using `DiffUtils` as it offers nice smooth animations when transitioning between lists in the adapter. This answer was just to get the ball rolling for you.

```
val diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(object : DiffUtil.Callback() {

                override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean = newList[newItemPosition] == oldList[oldItemPosition]

                override fun getOldListSize(): Int = oldList.size

                override fun getNewListSize(): Int = newList.size

                override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean = newList[newItemPosition] == oldList[oldItemPosition]
            }

diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(adapter)
```

Comment: l add your code in my main activity class or in  ListAdapte class ?

Comment: Add the method i suggested inside your adapter

Comment: l got error red line under `notifyDataSeChanged` . unresolved reference  `notifyDataSeChanged`

Comment: and in that case how l use search bar filter ? l mean  `val search= view.findViewById(R.id.searchFlightId) as EditText` used in method you 
suggested ?

Comment: Assuming it will be if an item in the list contains your search term?

Comment: yes  , check my update question  . l added search bar filter to search on any item inside listview but the there still not function to do this . l want function to do this operation in my list adater class

Comment: Updated my answer; in `searchList()` method i suggested you could use it like

`it.fieldA.contains(search.text.toString()) || it.fieldB.contains(search.text.toString())`

but replace `fieldA` and `fieldB` with whatever your model is composed of

Comment: my goodness , l still have a lot errors . `unresolved reference filteredList`  `unresolved referenceadapter ` . any way thanks for trying help me . l have to find another way .

Comment: I told you, you have to add these variables to your activity aha.
`val baseList: List<FlightShdu>` and 
`var filteredList: MutableList<FlightShdu> = mutableListOf()`

`adapter` reference will be whatever you have called your adapter

Next time you ask a question like this post all of your activity too so I can see the references pls

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184036/discussion-between-blue-jones-and-pabloescobar).

Comment: what about this topic ! https://camposha.info/android/kotlin-android-listview-searchview can you convert that code in link to my code ? and which class you need even l update my question

Comment: this will make the baselist change as well since the adapter is using the baselist refernce to avoid that only interact with filteredList in adapter (addAll to filteredList before passing to adapter)