# Should I use a different data structure or filter the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm using the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter to display a list of announcements to students in a university app training project I'm working on. The data is stored in the folowing structure:

each student has a department, year and a language field
[image: students reference]

each announcement has a targeted department, year and language
[image]
my goal is to only display the announcements that are targetted to the currently logged in student, but I couldn't find a way to perform such query in firebase database.

fetching all the announcements wouldn't cause any privacy issues, so I thought of filtering the data in the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter. I saw ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54248004/how-to-add-search-filter-in-recyclerview-from-firebase)) answer that implements a Filterable then calls the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getFilter().filter() method to do the filtering. However, I need to run the filter() method automatically everytime more data is fetched from the database and I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get only the announcements for the current user, you need to do two steps:

1. Load the current user, so you can look up their `department`.
2. Create a query for only the announcements of that department, something like:

Code:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getRef("Announcements").orderByChild("department").equalTo("CCNE");
```

You can then create the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` based on the query, instead of the direct reference to all `Announcements`.

Comment: My problem is that I can't do such query, because I need  to filter based on year and language too, not only the department

Comment: That would've been useful to include in your question. But see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase